# setting onclick in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm writing some function that is working with Facebook's API. I was previously setting the onclick attribute by taking the parent and saying something along the lines of `parent.innerHTML += "<a onclick = 'test("+parameter+")'>Previous</a>"` and that worked fine. But I wanted to make it safer and more to standard so it is styled as follows:

```
function myMethod(link){
    ...
    FB.api(link, function(response){
        ...
        if(value != null){
            var prev = document.createElement("a");
            prev.innerText = "previous";
            prev.setAttribute("id", "previous");
            //prev.onclick = function(){test(this);}; doesn't work here
            document.getElementById("facebook-photos").appendChild(prev);
        }
        //some other code (loops and stuff) including this 
        for(...){
           var container = document.createElement("div");
           container.classList.add("container");
           container.classList.add("thing");
           container.onclick = function(){test(this);}; // works here
        }
        //

        if(document.getElementById("previous")){
            document.getElementById("previous").onclick = function(){test(this);}; //works here   
        }
    }
}
```

yet for some reason whenever I try and use this, clicking the element does nothing. Inspecting the element shows no "onclick" field but displaying the element in the console shows that the onclick field is not null. Nothing is covering the element and I've tried it as a div and as a button. When I try and do document.getElementById("previous") earlier, it still doesn't work. **Why does this happen? Is it just the asynchronous nature of Javascript?** The assignment in the middle works even though its relatively soon after the creation of the element, but the one at the beginning does not.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and setting breakpoints?

Comment: did you tried - **prev.onclick = function(){test(prev);};** as you are passing whole element in test(), so may be this should work.

Comment: The onclick doesn't work because it's commented out. :D

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging and setting break points, but for some reason it does the line where it assigns the onclick the function, but it does not ever get triggered, so any break points inside of the function are never called @Dai

Comment: @VikashSingh calling `test(this);` will essentially do that.

Comment: @MichaelNakayama Is it possible that your webpage has multiple elements with `id="previous"`?

Comment: @MichaelNakayama `test(this);` will not necessarily always work. The `this` reference in JavaScript is fickle, especially if you're using it with closures (as you are) and event-handlers.

Comment: @Dai I'll defer to you on the `this` but I will say, it doesn't work with just `test`. Also, I've echoed the contents of a `$('#previous')` request, and there is only one.